# Could not find or load main class seleniumauto.main

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to browse google.com using Selenium.
My IDE is Eclipse, this is my code:

```
package seleniumauto;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    
    }
}
```

I get the following error :

```
WARNING: Unknown module: selrnium specified to --patch-module
Error: Could not find or load main class selrniumauto.main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: selrniumauto.main
```

Comment: Did you download and run the selenium Chrome driver? You have to seperately download the selenium driver for your browser and run it in the background. If you don't want to do this you can look at this https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager.

Comment: Looks like your definition of the main type to execute has a typo in it.
It tries to find "selrnium.main" (beware the "R" at position 4) while your actual class is "selenium.main".